# Removing access to WIN+L keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-events

In using AutoHotKey to block access to ALL keys, all keyboard shortcuts do stop working and the windows key on its own can be blocked i.e.

```
LWin::Return
RWin::Return
```

also all other keyboard shortcuts are blocked, however windows + L seems to operate on a higher level and works regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Autohotkey actually can disable the <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> combination, but it can be done through the registry. Here are detailed instructions: [How to Disable the Lock Screen Shortcut Key (Win + L) in Windows](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-lock-screen-shortcut-key-windows/).

To summarize:

1. In the registry editor, navigate to this key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies`.
2. Add a new key, "System", in "Policies".
3. In your newly created "System" key, add a new "DWORD (32-bit) Value".
4. Name the value “DisableLockWorkstation” and set its value data to "1".
5. Log off/on or restart.

Note that I haven't verified if this works. Also note that the linked instructions also includes steps to disable all WinKey combos if that is your desire.